# Parse Apache logfile and ban IPs

Tags: iptables, logging, web, ddos, parsing

My server is under attack, it is flooded with request with the following pattern:

Thousands of IPs
Each IP request the same page "GET / HTTP/1.1" with the same referrer 3-5 times per second (same timestamp).

So what I would need is a small shell script which takes the input from "tail -f /var/www/log/access.log" and parses the same for repeated requests with the same timestamp (say 2 request for the same page with same referrer and same time) and adds a iptable rule to drop all packets from this IP.

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) and at this [Howto](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Apache) for an example of filters for Apache log files.

Here's an example that should accomplish what you ask. Please see the [manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) and adjust to your needs:

`/etc/fail2ban/filters.d/apache-attackers.conf`

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST> - - [[^]]+] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 .* "REFERER"
```

`/etc/fail2ban/local.jail`

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 <an IP you access the system from>

[apache-attackers]
enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-attackers
bantime = 86400
logpath = /var/log/httpd/*access_log
maxretry = 5
```

Enable `fail2ban` at startup (RHEL/CentOS) and launch it:

```
chkconfig fail2ban on
service fail2ban start
```

Note: Tested on RHEL/CentOS, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Referers change all the time, can Fail2Ban handle this ? I am looking over the wiki but it doesnt seems so

Comment: @Iain answer has been updated, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much,this seems to help a bit, but now i found a new pattern. Maybe i may ask you again for help to rewrite this [Definition] to catch all IPs which access multiple times the same page at the same timestamp; forgetting all togheter about referer because they also change.

Log looks like this:

186.6.65.199 - - [06/May/2013:18:46:21 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10488 "http://coolsearch37845.com/b/eve/618aef08......
186.6.65.199 - - [06/May/2013:18:46:21 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10531 "https://liteapps.mcafee.com.......

Comment: @Jmaxor adding an ignoreregex line with something like `"[^"]+(?:-|google|bing|...|your-domains)[^"]+` for the referer field might do the trick.